# Make View Visible or Gone in adapter on ClickListener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, firebaseui, onitemclicklistener

Iam showing the a recyclerview in my app and I want when user click on the recyclerview item a hidden view should be visible to him and on clicking back the item it should gone.
My code :

```
 holder.parentView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                    if (viewVisibiltyCheck) {
                        holder.expandView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        viewVisibiltyCheck = false;
                    } else {
                        viewVisibiltyCheck = true;
                        holder.expandView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                });
```

Iam using Firebase Recycler.I have a boolean check which is when true view become visible of which ever item in list I click and make boolean false.Now if I click on the same item it will work fine and hide the view but if I will click on any other item in list with first view being visible I have to double click the item because at first click it will make boolean true as it become false when I click on the first item list and then on second click it will show me the view .

Is there any logic I can do all with single click? Thanku

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need that viewVisibilityCheck at all.

```
holder.parentView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                    if (holder.expandView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                        holder.expandView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        holder.expandView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks mate that what I was finding,I wasn't able to remember the statement.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your problem is that the `viewVisibiltyCheck` value is not connected to the right item you are clicking. If that's the case just set the `viewVisibiltyCheck` as a property of the `holder`, so you'll access it the same as the `expandView`.

So something like this maybe:

```
holder.parentView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                    if (holder.viewVisibiltyCheck) {
                        holder.expandView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.viewVisibiltyCheck = false;
                    } else {
                        holder.viewVisibiltyCheck = true;
                        holder.expandView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                });
```

**EDIT:**
You need to put it where you create the holder and its views, like the expandView. In this way you can associated various parameters to the view, but Bruce answer it's easier probably in your case.

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View expandView;
    boolean viewVisibiltyCheck;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
         /* your code */
        viewVisibiltyCheck = false;
    }
```

Comment: How should I set the viewVisibiltyCheck as a property of the holder?
You just pasted from question

Comment: I dont think we can do it that way  viewVisibiltyCheck is just a boolean value.
Thanku for your time though

Comment: Where you create the holder and its views, like the expandView. In this way you can associated various parameters to the view, but Bruce answer it's easier probably in your case.

`public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View expandView;
    boolean viewVisibiltyCheck;
    
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
         /* your code */
        viewVisibiltyCheck = false;
    }`

Comment: Ok I got your point we can also do that way but Bruce logic is simple as you said.
Thanku